# RHEL 5.5 : how to install packages using yum

Tags: installation, yum, rhel-5

I have a RHEL 5.5 workstation where I'm trying to install chrome, mc, etc. However, I get the following error.

```
[root@munsharm-lnx user_options_dir]# yum install mc
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package mc available.
Nothing to do
[root@munsharm-lnx user_options_dir]#
```

How do I solve this issue ? 
How can I add the repositories from, say, CentOS, to get mc, chromium, etc ?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you do any googling first?  What did you find out?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manage packages on different linux distributives](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&id=4CD1B952A2640E72!233#cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&id=4CD1B952A2640E72!1087)

[image]